# problem generating graphics (argument 1 has unexpected type 'float')

Tags: python, qt, graphics, tree, ete3

I am trying to generate a phylogenetic tree using this code

```
#!/bin/python3
import re
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
import sys
import ete3

from ete3 import Tree
from ete3.treeview import NodeStyle
from ete3 import TreeStyle

def get_tree_dist():
    '''
    Read in the data and draw the tree with branch lengths
    '''
    # Read in the data
    alignment_file = "MK.fasta"
    with open("MK.fasta", "r") as f:
        fasta_content = f.read()

    # Create the Tree object
    t = Tree("MK.fasta.treefile")

    # Create a TreeStyle object
    ts = TreeStyle()
    ts.show_leaf_name = True
    ts.show_branch_length = True
    ts.show_branch_support = True
    ts.scale = 150
    # set the DPI value
    dpi = 100
    # Draw the tree
    t.render("MK_tree.png", w=1000, h=800, units="px", tree_style=ts, dpi=int(dpi))

    # Resize the image
    img = Image.open("MK_tree.png")
    img = img.resize((int(img.width * 300 / dpi), int(img.height * 300 / dpi)))
    img.save("MK_tree.png", dpi=(300, 300))
    # Change the DPI of the image
    ii = QImage()
    ii.load("MK_tree.png")
    ii.setDotsPerMeterX(int(dpi / 0.0254)) # Convert inches to meters
    ii.setDotsPerMeterY(int(dpi / 0.0254)) # Convert inches to meters
    ii.save("MK_tree.png")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_tree_dist()
```

But when I run it I got this message:

QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-xxx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/d/tree3.py", line 47, in 
get_tree_dist()

File "/mnt/d/tree3.py", line 33, in get_tree_dist
t.render("rbcL_tree.png", w=1000, h=800, units="px", tree_style=ts, dpi=int(dpi))

File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ete3/coretype/tree.py", line 1392, in render
return drawer.render_tree(self, file_name, w=w, h=h,

File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ete3/treeview/drawer.py", line 113, in render_tree
x_scale, y_scale = save(scene, imgName, w=w, h=h, units=units, dpi=dpi)

File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ete3/treeview/main.py", line 754, in save
ii.setDotsPerMeterX(dpi / 0.0254) # Convert inches to meters

TypeError: setDotsPerMeterX(self, a0: int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'

I do not know what else to do. Someone could help me please.

Comment: Try passing in `100` rather than `dpi`.

Comment: It seems you are using an old PyQt. Install the recent version of PyQt5.